# Removing empty list items in ONE div using jquery

Tags: jquery, listitem

I'm trying to remove empty list items in a div named 'reviews'. Currently this works for the entire page however I want it to work only in one div

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('ul li:empty').remove();
});
```

I've tried the below with no success

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#reviews ul li:empty').remove();
});
```

Comment: well your code should work, make sure you are writing the id name correct or its not a class

Comment: Thanks @Tushar seems like I was having a conflict with jQuery, i managed to fix it by adding the line 'jQuery.noConflict(true);'

Answer (score 0):

You can loop that list :

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   $('#reviews ul li').each(function(){
     var elem = $(this);
     if(elem.is(':empty')){
        elem.remove();
     }
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this code does indeed work however it appears to not have been the problem. Many thanks regardless!